how to prevent maven to download an excluded transitive dependency (not exists in dependency:tree output)
I have a project with dependency tree like below.
    <dependency>
     <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
     <artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
    </dependency>

I excluded log4j 1.2.14 which my dependency xxxxxx uses and added log4j-api and log4j-core  as new dependencies.
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.17.1</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

Finally, log4j 1.2.14 seems removed from dependency:tree output but when running "mvn clean and install" command it is still downloaded. Is there a way to prevent this version to be downloaded?

Is the *.jar downloaded? Clean your local Maven repository in ~/.m2/repository/log4j and check if the file appears. The *.pom is downloaded to build the dependency tree, before exclusions are applied.

Yes After I deleted the directory from local repository, It was downloaded again and includes jar file as well.

It must be included transitively by some other artifact. Did you check if this version is included in any of log4j-api or log4j-core?

What does mvn dependency:resolve-plugins say? Maven plugins can also use log4j:log4j, see this question for example.

@Vishal Yes I checked and it was not included in any versions of log4j-api or log4j-core.

Good catch @PiotrP.Karwasz , It seems used by one of the plugins in my project. Thanks

Could you write an answer and tell us which? If the xxxxx dependency is public, could you say which dependency it is? Pure logging APIs like commons-logging are available since the early 2000, I thought that libraries using Log4j 1 directly (API + implementation tight together) didn't exist any more.

xxxxxx dependency is an internal artifact developed by our company internally. By adding exclusion for log4j, I assumed log4j should not be downloaded anymore.  But it was still being downloaded. By running "mvn dependency:resolve-plugins" as @Piotr P. Karwasz recommended, I noticed log4j-1.x.x is used by another internally developed maven plugin. By upgrading this plugin to used log4j 2 supported version, I fixed my problem.
